# Can you write one program around multiple userform textboxes which addresses the one that is active

Tags: object, reference, textbox, userform

First time on here as I'm writing a program to help with my job but am a bit stuck :( Thanks in advance :)

I have a userform with 72 textboxes over 6 multipages (12 per page) and want to write one single program which will work when any one of the textboxes is selected rather than write individual programs for each textbox.

I am actually using the textboxes as selection buttons. I did originally manage to do what I wanted with commandbuttons using [ **fmCalc.MultiPage2.Pages(MultiPage2.Value).ActiveControl.Caption** ] to recognise which commandbutton had been pressed, which worked great for getting data from the active button, but when I came to change the button caption I realised it only lasted until the userform was closed (then reset to blank captions on re activating of the userform)

1. If you make changes to a userform done via programming, can you save the userform in that state so the changes don't disapear?
2. Can you write a single program to recognise which textbox, of many, is "active"?

cheers